# Cordova + Android: How to stop shrinking of screen if virtual keyboard is displayed?

Tags: android, css, cordova

Helo,

I have a problem with screen shrinking on Android devices if virtual keyboard is displayed.I would like to keep screen without shrinking.

See image below:

[image]

How can i do it please?

Cordova version is 4.2.0

Many thanks fro any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to AndroidManifest.xml, in your main activity add the two properties

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

Hope it might solve your problem.